# manual generated toc page with wraps an tab stops

Tags: table-of-contents, wrap, csv

My last deeper contact with TeX was many years ago. Since then I use it only from time to time to assemble PDF pages with bookmarks etc.
Now I need to manually create TOC pages for a collection of many PDFs. Therefore I have a CSV file with a list of toc entries, for example

```
"chapter";"text";"page number"
"1";"Recipes";"1"
"2";"This is a long, a very, super, mega, ultra, extreme and extraordinary long text for a simple description";"5"
"3";"Something completely different";"12"
```

Can someone help me out with suggesting TeX code of the above example that looks like this: http://test.lars-uhlmann.de/Katalog_Index_Layout_Description.pdf

many thanks
Lars

Comment: You want to know how to style the toc, did i get that right? Or are you asking how to read the `csv` and output LaTeX code?

Comment: sorry: to style the toc

Comment: A toc usually is a piece in a larger document, all margins should be consistent in a document. What do you mean by »background of the page«? Can you make some explanations?

Comment: I am not sure i get you right here. You want to create a table, that coincidently looks like a toc, right?

Comment: It is not clear what your are asking for. You already have PDFs lacking tables of contents? or you have many PDFs, and you want to create a new one with  a table of contents whose entries correspond to those PDFs (as in `one chapter=one pdf`). Also, are you using `Plain TeX` or `LaTeX` or...